# Expressing constant of integration as its natural log in 1st order linear ODE

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the complete reasoning behind constants of integration, specifically in the case of the natural log?

Given $\int\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)dx=\int(dt)$, I obtain:

$\ln\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)=t+C$

My textbook gives the solution for this problem as:

$\ln\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)=t+\ln(C)$

Why is the constant of integration expressed as its natural log in this case? Is it simply a matter of notation for convenience's sake?

Comment: Of course, both $C$ are constants and moreover ANY constants. But they are not equal. If this confuses you, do not use the same symbol for both : $c_1$ for the first and $c_2$ for the second. Then $c_1=\ln|c_2|$. The textbook uses the symbol $C$. Do not use the same symbol, for example write $c$ instead of $C$ and you will see the Relationship between both.

Comment: The first integral should be $dx$, not $dt$. And the logarithm should be of the absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)dx=\ln\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)+C_1$$

$$\int(dt)=t+C_2$$
Hense, from : $\int\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)dx=\int(dt)$ :

$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)+C_1=t+C_2$$

$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)=t+C_2-C_1$$

Let $C=e^{C2-C_1}\quad\to\quad C_2-C_1=\ln(C)$

$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)=t+\ln(C)$$

This is what your text book gives.

Comment: The first integral should be $dx$, not $dt$. And the logarithm should be of the absolute value.

Comment: @ LutzL : Of couse ! About the absolute value : Since the text book write it so, I let it so, to not be more papist than the Pope (and for benefit of laziness).

Comment: I have edited the question as I'm not certain when to apply this simplification.

Comment: If the wording of the problem changes, of course, the solution changes. This is no longer the same question.

Comment: Roger that, asked follow up (full) question separately.

Comment: @0x1000001 : You wrote : "I have edited the question as I'm not certain when to apply this simplification". What simplification are you talking about ?